# Is checking if a value is 0 faster than just overwriting it?

Tags: java, optimization

Let's just say I have an array which contains some numbers contained between 1 and 9, and another array of 9 elements which contains every number from 1 to 9 (1, 2, 3, ... 9). I want to read every number from the first array, and when I read the number X, put to 0 the X value in the second array (which would be contained in second_array[X-1]). Is it faster for the CPU to do this:

```
//size is the size of the first array
int temp = 0;

for(int i; i < size; i++)
{
    temp = first_array[i];
    if(second_array[temp-1] != 0) second_array[temp-1]= 0;
}
```

Or the same without the control:

```
int temp = 0;

for(int i; i < size; i++)
{
    temp = first_array[i];
    second_array[temp-1]= 0;
}
```

To be clear: does it take more time to make a control on the value, or to overwrite it? I need my code to execute as fast as possible, so every nanosecond saved would be useful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you profile your code?

Comment: Why would you put `if(second_array[size-1] != 0) second_array[size-1]= 0;` or `second_array[size-1]= 0;` inside the loop? It does the same every iteration since `size` does not change in the loop. Maybe you meant `second_array[i-1]` or `secon_array[temp-1]` ?

Comment: Yes, that was what I meant, thanks for making me notice it. Fixed.

Comment: Generally speaking, I have never seen this type of code before (the one with the if condition), so I am assuming that this shouldn't make any difference or improvement. The assumption being, if it was better, it would have been widely known.

Comment: Maybe there's no big advantage in using one rather than the another, but I still need the code to be as fast as possible, so every bit of time saved would be important.

Answer (score 2):

The second version is more performant, as is does not require the check, which will happen in every iteration of the loop and only in one case yield true.

Furthermore you can improve even more if you write:

```
for(int i; i < size; i++)
{
    temp = first_array[i];
}
second_array[size-1]= 0;
```

Comment: Am I missing something, or does this code do nothing of what OP wanted?

Comment: It doesn't do what I wanted, even if it was my mistake to write the code wrong in the first place. Just read the edited one.

Comment: @rents I was reading the code that OP wanted, along with the comments, so i know that current version is what it was supposed to look like, but still: I'm not sure if this answer is true, but the code posted by hotzst currently does a useless loop and sets one value to 0.

Comment: Yep, it does that. Definitely not what I wanted (even though it does what my miswritten code did).

Answer (score 0):

Writing data to memory is always fast when comparing to if condition.

*Reason* - to compare two values,you need to read them first and then you need to perform comparison.While in other case,you are simply writing data to memory which does not care about anything.

Comment: I am not an expert on the JVM, or modern processor architectures, but what about updating and flushing caches?

Comment: I wonder this too. Cause the user above you says that just checking would be faster because it won't require the cache to flush.

Comment: @ThomasPadron-McCarthy the next instruction by definition does not depend on the write, so it can just go ahead while the write is pending. Reads hold stuff up anything that depends on them. The branch will be speculated even so (sort of breaking the dependency) but will be slow when mispredicted.

Comment: Actually, in order to write some data, the CPU usually needs to read it first. The main reason being - most caches only work with full line granularity, so you need to fill an entire cache line (usually 64B)

Answer (score 0):

If the value is checked repeatedly, it may be cached in the CPU cache and accessed much faster from there than from the main RAM. Differently, writing the value requires this value to make all the way to the main memory that may take more time. Writing may be deferred, but the dirty cache row must be flushed sooner or later.

Hence the version that only repeatedly reads may be faster than the version that repeatedly writes.

Comment: What about what the other user is saying?

    >to compare two values,you need to read them first and then you 
    >need to perform comparison.While in other case,you are simply
    >writing data to memory which does not care about anything.

Comment: multiple writes will be merged in the cache, you don't have to write all the way to memory every time. Also, to read something meaningful you must have written it earlier, so the line may still be dirty in the cache.

Comment: So, in the end, has someone understood which way would be faster?

Comment: This depends on too many things. Best, I would say, do profiling.

Answer (score 0):

You can just go with:

```
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    second_array[first_array[i]-1]= 0;
}
```

Even if the check is faster (i doubt it), it would only be faster if a large part of the `second_array` started as 0, as any non 0 location requires two operations.

Anyway, the best way to figure out the answer to these kind of questions is to use run it and benchmark! A quick benchmark on my side shows it is 60% slower if `second_array` does not contain zero's, but 50% faster when `second_array` is all zero's! That would lead me to conclude the check is faster if more than 55% of `second_array` start zeroed out.

Comment: I used the temp size just to make the code more readable, so you can even remove the last line in your code (I don't need to have the size stored in a value). Anyway, I know that sometimes the compiler itself changes stuff to make things faster, but I'd rather not rely on it.

Comment: @JohnStrife I've removed my remark about the compiler - it's simply not true -. These kind of optimizations work if you have prior knowledge about the content of `second_array`, something the compiler doesn't have. A quick benchmark showed me interesting results.